# How to add "Content-Type = application/json;v=2.0" including versioning with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, aspnet-api-versioning

Sorry to ask this question like this. I can give you the feeling I would like you to do the code for me. I already spent a day tying to write the code to send a http request that contains a header with versioning:

For versioning I use the [versioning by Media Type](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Versioning-by-Media-Type) from Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning project.

My API part is working fine and I can request the correct version without problem with Postman:

[image]

You see this line "Content-Type = application/json;v=2.0"? On postman no problem. With HttpClient from C# impossible to do.

Let me copy pas here all solution I tried with they error. I will Edit this question each time I try a new solution. By facility, but also to be more clear I will copy paste images:

Solution 1:
The extension method with new Content = ...

[image]

Solution 1B:
From BeginnerTejas

[image]

Solution 1C:
From BeginnerTejas but using MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue now

[image]

Solution 2:
The extension method with request.Headers.Add(...)

[image]

Solution 3: 
BaseProxy with Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(...)
It seems I cannot add any "Content-Type"

[image]

Solution 4:
BaseProxy with Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(...)

[image]

Solution 5:
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

[image]

Comment: have you tried ApiVersion attribute?

Comment: ApiVersion attribute is for Server side. Yes all my API use the [ControllerName("Client")] then [ApiVersion("2.0")] similar settings. Again, server is working fine. I can send all my requests from Postman. Problem is how to add a header with HttpClient?

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue( "application/json" )
{
    Parameters = { new NameValueHeaderValue( "v", "2.0" ) }
};
```

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' on request.Content. I can fix that but I think it is my solution 1. Already tested. Can you crosscheck if you see any difference?

Comment: you added this code in your solution 2 approach correct?

Comment: solution 1 actually.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (or at least *shouldn't*) use `Content-Type` when you don't send any content. Use the `Accept` header for `GET` and `DELETE` requests like this:

```
request.Headers.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json; v=2.0"));
```

If both headers are specified `Content-Type` is considered before `Accept`. If `Accept` specifies multiple media types with a version, the one with the highest *quality* is matched. Mixing versions per request (e.g. send 2.0, but receive 1.0) is not supported. Negotiating multiple media types with a version is also not currently supported (aside from *quality*).

---

UPDATE: I wanted to expand the answer to include the fact that there are now API version-aware client extensions (in [Asp.Versioning.Http.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.Http.Client)) that make this process significantly simpler. For example:

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();

// register the default api version writer for all requests
services.AddSingleton<IApiVersionWriter>( new MediaTypeApiVersionWriter() );

// you can also provide a client-specific writer here ↓
services.AddHttpClient( "Example" ).AddApiVersion( 1.0 );

// using dependency injection with the http client factory
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var factory = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
var client = factory.CreateClient( "Example" );

// this will add 'v=1.0' to Accept
var response = await client.GetAsync( "http://tempuri.org" );

// this will add 'v=1.0' to Content-Type
response = await client.PostJsonAsync( "http://tempuri.org", new { test = true } );
```

If you're not using the DI extensions or `IHttpClientFactory` you can still add the `ApiVersionHandler` directly to the handler chain in your `HttpClient`.